# SAX Parser without defining tags in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

Is it possible to parse the XML files from SAX parser without defining the tags name in Java file? I want to make my code generic so that it can parse any kind of XML file rather than some specific XML files.

Comment: A SAX Parser is a generic XML parser already. What do you really want to do?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. However, it rather depends on what you want your application to do with the output from the SAX parser.

Comment: What solution are you using to parse xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for XML-to-Object "parser" with externalized mapping (e.g. XML, annotations) or an implied convention. Here's a list to chose from:

- [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)
- [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/)
- [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)
- [JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/)
- [Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/)

you will sure find more. If you would rather parse your XML by hand using SAX (or DOM, or StAX) then you **have** to know the names of the XML tags you are interested in. You can abstract them out and make your parser configuration driven but if you are constructing objects from your XML data then your time is better spent picking a framework that can do it for you

Comment: Thank you Pravel Veller for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Have a look at [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/), [DOM4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) and [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/). They are all parsing XML through SAX and building a tree a of nodes. However, it is unclear what you mean by "without defining the tags name in Java file".